# Displaying .h associated with .m automatically in AppCode

Tags: jetbrains-ide, appcode

Is there a feature in JetBrains AppCode allowing to display automatically the .h associated with the opened .m file (and the other way around).

The associated file would be displayed in a tab of a splitted window (Available through the AppCode menu "Window > Editor Tabs > Split Vertically").

I'm looking for a feature similar to Xcode "automatic counterparts" feature (see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbH8r.png )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in an automatic way. But BTW: Xcode almost never displays what you need in the Assistant Editor.

Similar to Xcode, it's possible to switch between .h und .m files with a key command. Having switched, you might want to open e.g. .m file in a split editor (as you described it). Then simply switch back to the .h file in the original window - and there you are.

It takes some more time to get into AppCode. But it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the command you mention, it's very useful !
To be complete, it is available through the AppCode menu "Navigate > Related Symbol..." but you should use the shortcut for it obviously.

Comment: Adding to @smoldersan comment :
The default in Xcode to switch between .h and .m files is ⌘^↑ and ⌘^↓. 
For appcode, it is ⌘⌥↖︎ (cmd + alt + fn + left-arrow). 
You can change this from Preferences -> Keymap and then search for Related Symbol.